# How to add vertical lines in the next several bars after input the time? (pinescript)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work. I tried to make the vertical line 10 bars after the input.time

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mulitple bars after time input", overlay = true)
 
// Date/Time Input
inp_time1 = input.time(timestamp("21 Mar 2022 00:00 +0000"), "Date", confirm = true)

var barCount1 = 0
barCount1 := inp_time1 ? 0 : barCount1 + 1

if barCount1 == 10
    line.new(bar_index, open, bar_index, close, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the counter and added an input time check instead, you can directly add the value to the bar_index to make it plot to the right, with input for example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mulitple bars after time input", overlay = true)
 
// Date/Time Input
inp_time1 = input.time(timestamp("21 Mar 2022 00:00 +0000"), "Date", confirm = true)
inp_bars = input.int(10, 'Bars to the Right')

if time >= inp_time1 and time[1] < inp_time1
    line.new(bar_index + inp_bars, open, bar_index + inp_bars, close, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works perfectly! Can you help me with this one please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980158/how-to-find-a-value-on-a-spesific-single-bar-with-input-time-and-input-source

Comment: Just added the answer, you can also mark the answer as accepted if the issue is resolved, You're welcome ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for bothering you

Comment: I want to ask again, is it possible to change the 'bar' into 'day'?