# How to find a value on a spesific single bar with input.time and input.source? (pinescript)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to change the 'inp_bars1' with some math calculations, so I need the close value with 'input.source' in the time that I choose with 'input.time'. But I don't know how to connect them.
Here is my code.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mulitple bars after time input", overlay = true)
 
// Date/Time Input
inp_time1 = input.time(timestamp("21 Mar 2022 00:00 +0000"), "Date", confirm = true)
source = input.source(close, "Source")

inp_bars1 = 10

if time >= inp_time1 and time[1] < inp_time1
    line.new(bar_index + inp_bars1, open, bar_index + inp_bars1, close, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same time condition to store the input.source()'s value at the given date, see the **dateSource** variable below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mulitple bars after time input", overlay = true)
 
// Date/Time Input
inp_time1 = input.time(timestamp("21 Mar 2022 00:00 +0000"), "Date", confirm = true)
source = input.source(close, "Source")

inp_bars1 = 10

var float dateSource = na

if time >= inp_time1 and time[1] < inp_time1
    dateSource := source
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(dateSource))
    line.new(bar_index + inp_bars1, open, bar_index + inp_bars1, close, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
```